# Checking for Reactions in Discord.Net (C#)

Tags: c#, discord.net

I need some help with **Discord.Net**. I have the following command written down:

```cs
    [Command("project", RunMode=RunMode.Async)]
    public async Task Project(string action, string id="")
    {
        switch(action)
        {
            case "post":
                {
                    StringCreator tagger = new StringCreator();
                    string index = tagger.Get(5);
                    var project=await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("project-id-" + index);

                    var message = await project.SendMessageAsync("What language is this project in?");
                    var rMessage = message.Id;
                    await message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(""));
                    await message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(""));
                    await message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(""));

                    break;
                }
         }
```

Now I tried making an event like this:

```cs
 public async Task OnReactionAddedEvent(SocketReaction reaction)
        {
            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "English";
            }

            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "Hebrew";
            }

            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "Romanian";
            }

        }
```

If I try to use it like this, just before the break in my command function:

```cs
_discord.ReactionAdded += OnReactionAddedEvent;
```

I tried editing my Event Method to take the marameter as cacheable but with no luck:

```cs
public async Task OnReactionAddedEvent(Cacheable<SocketReaction> reaction)
        {
            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "English";
            }

            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "Hebrew";
            }

            if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                vars.projectLang = "Romanian";
            }

        }
```

Whatever I do, when declaring it in the command method, the whole statement  shows up as an error. I'm at a loss, please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two things. First the signature for the event handler should be `(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong>, ISocketMessageChannel, SocketReaction)`. Second you can't hook the event in your command, it's not going to work.

Comment: Then how do I go about counting the reactions within a command?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Anu6is The command creates a new channel, sends in a message into that channel asking for the language of the project, and reacts with the flags of the supported languages. I want to get the reaction added by the user. Based on that reaction, the `vars.projectLang` string will take the values coresponding to the country selected.

Comment: You can hook the reaction added event outside of the command and add some logic to figure out which message the reaction was added to and whatever additional logic is required or you can look into using https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive. If the user is meant to make one selection the Interactive package may be more suitable.

Comment: @Anu6is I have never developed a bot before. Would you be so kind as to provide me with a little bit more detail as to how I get to do that? Even so, declaring it outside the command doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can join https://discord.gg/discord-api and go to the `dotnet_discort-net` channel